# Access - Is there some way to overwrite MS Access database old data

Tags: ms-access

Is there some way to overwrite MS Access database old data. like I wanna set a limit for a database, when the record meet the limit, new data overwrite old data.

And there is not so much record in my access database, but database file size go to 2G.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run a _Compact and Repair_.

Comment: And unless you have masses of data your description is not very sound. You archive data, or better still mark it as archived , but shouldn't really ever delete it.